# mimic jquery ui dialog button style

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, styles

Can anyone tell me what class name to specify for an html button, e.g,

```
<div id='dlg' class='dialog'>
 <input type="text" id="client" name="client" />
 <button type='button' class='WHAT_CLASS' onclick="afunction()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I want same button appearance jquery ui 'Redmond' style applies by default

```
$dlg.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Company name',
  buttons: {
  'Cancel': function() {
    $dlg.dialog('close');
     }, ......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple necessary classes!
You should use the jQuery UI functionality for that:

```
$("button").button();
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

However, if you can't do this, the classes jQuery adds are:
`ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all`

Comment: Thank you guys. I had tried ui-button without success. Binarious explained and his solution worked, the only thing different is now 'no padding', button wraps tightly round button caption, but I can hopefully find out why now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery UI included in your page, then the class name is `ui-button`. Edit: There are other classes in addition, such as `ui-state-default`, etc. that will depend on the state of the button. The easiest way to emulate this behavior is to not emulate it at all -- use jQuery UI as it was intended.

Comment: Understand now. My problem is I'm trying to move over to jquery gradually whilst learning it. My application is complex and works perfectly so I don't want to break it on the way. But responses from you guys is so well-informed, many thanks.